# Postgresql dense_rank manipulation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
     Name     | Time  |  
     Sam      | 10:58 | 
     Sam      | 10:59 | 
     Sam      | 11:10 |   
     Tom      | 1:16  |   
     Tom      | 1:17  |   
     Tom      | 2:10  |  
     Tom      | 3:44  | 
     Tom      | 3:45  |
```

So basically, it's a table that logs a person's activity and shows the time of activity as well. Anything that appears on this table is an offence and they are usually grouped together with little info.  As a rule of thumb, if the time of activity is not more than 3 minutes apart, they are considered the same offense/infraction. So a person can have multiple entries in the table but they might belong to the same infraction/have multiple entries and belong to different infractions.

Ideally I would want the table to look something like this:

```
 Name     | Time  | Infraction Number|  
 Sam      | 10:58 |         1        |
 Sam      | 10:59 |         1        |
 Sam      | 11:10 |         2        |  
 Tom      | 1:16  |         1        |  
 Tom      | 1:17  |         1        |  
 Tom      | 2:10  |         2        | 
 Tom      | 3:44  |         3        | 
 Tom      | 3:45  |         3        |
```

Is there anyway I can make use of dense_rank to do something like this in postgresql?

Comment: "As a rule of thumb" -- Rules of thumb don't work for computers. Your rule of thumb doesn't cover 10:58 / 11:00 / 11:02. Your rule of thumb says 10:58 and 11:00 are the same infraction, 11:00 and 11:02 are the same infraction, but 10:58 and 11:02 *aren't* the same infraction. Can you be more precise in specifying what behaviour you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,
       EXTRACT( HOUR FROM  time1 )||':'||EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM  time1 ) AS             Newtime ,       
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY new_time ) AS Infraction_Number
  FROM
    (
        SELECT name,
               time1,             
               CASE WHEN ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lag ) )/ 60 IS NULL OR 
                         ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lead ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) )/ 60 = 1 
                    THEN time1
                    WHEN ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lag ) )/ 60 = 1
                    THEN time1_lag
                    WHEN ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lag ) )/ 60 <> 1
                    THEN time1
                    WHEN ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lag ) )/ 60 IS NULL OR
                         ( EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1_lead ) - EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM time1 ) )/ 60 = 1
                    THEN time1 
                END AS new_time                        
          FROM
            (
                SELECT name, 
                       time1, 
                       LAG( time1, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time1 ) AS time1_lag,
                       LEAD( time1, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time1 ) AS time1_lead
                  FROM Yourtable
            )  
    )   ;
```